# Powershell 5.1 - Cannot find type [MyType]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

I have a generic module `MyModule.psm1` which creates and returns any custom type provided:

```
function Create-CustomType {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [System.Reflection.TypeInfo] $CustomType
    )
    // Some irrelevant logic ..................................................//
    
    return New-Object -TypeName $CustomType.FullName -Property $objectProperties
}
```

Also, I have some custom types, defined in the separate file `types.ps1`:

```
class User{
    // Some properties
}
```

Last, but not least I have a `RunMyLogic.ps1` script, which looks like that:

```
Import-Module -Name "$pathToMyCustomModulesFolder\\MyModule.psm1"
. ($PSScriptRoot + '\types.ps1')
# New-Object -TypeName $CustomType.FullName -Property $objectProperties
Create-CustomType -CustomType ([User])
```

The problem is that when I run `RunMyLogic.ps1`, my `Create-CustomType` function fails with the message `Cannot find type [User]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded`.

If I create a `User` directly in `RunMyLogic.ps1` then it works just fine (see commented line). But when I pass it to the `MyModule.psm1` it fails. Please, help to figure out what's wrong with it

Comment: The custom type can't be resolved by name from within the module. Change the parameter type to `[System.Type]` and use `$CustomType::new()` instead of `New-Object`.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen That might work, but I have $objectProperties with values. And I don't see an easy way to initialize all these properties if I use #type::new()

Comment: Is `$objectProperties` a dictionary? `$objectProperties -as $CustomType`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes, it is a hashset with actual values

Comment: It won't work with a hashset, but if it's a hashtable (which is also a kind of dictionary), then `-as [type]` will work

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I didn't really expect to get the help so quickly, thank you, sir, very much! I was looking through the Internat/reading/googling and I haven't seen anything like `custom type can't be resolved by name from within the module`? But it explains everything, except the Why question))) If you can share an article or reference to docs, where I can read more details I will appreciate it